# Starting with azure development as a company

Tags: azure

We are a small company and are still unsure how to start all this azure stuff.

Ok, we are clear on the technicalities like table storage and queues and all the that stuff, what we don't know about at all is how to set up the organization around developing for our developers. Which/how many azure accounts, shared or individual ones.

So far we've done classic windows development, so everyone has his environment, unit tests run either locally or on the build server (after pushing to mercurial or git), deployment from the build server.

The thing is that we want to use Azure not just as a hoster, but the full set, like blob/document/table storage, event hubs, storage queues, ReliableActors and everything. Things we can't do locally.

What's the appropriate way for azure then? There are about 20 to 30 developers and most have the enterprise msdn subscription.

What is a "company or organisation" account for? Should developers have their own accounts? Does DevOps need their passwords for all the bamboo or jenkins build stuff?

Comment: To the guy who downvoted it and set the close request: If you think that stackoverflow is the wrong place to ask this, I would be truly thankful for a pointer to a better place.

Comment: If you're actually thinking about transitioning an entire company over to Azure you should reach out to an MS sales rep. They will definitely be able to help you out. Going to vote to close this as well as it's definitely not the kind of question for SO

Comment: Ah - no, not the company. We just want to start providing solutions (mostly web solutions) to customers. And we have not found much about the DevOps stuff yet and how to handle all the things that can not be executed on the developer's local machine.

Comment: @Volker here's a pointer: programmers.se

Comment: @Volker, I think this is a relevant question for a DevOps forum. Not sure which SO site that is best for this purpose. It seems you would like to go all-in and re-architect for the cloud, not just "shift and lift" existing sites/apps. Looking at guidances for Azure (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/guidance/#checklists) it is not pinpointing the DevOps aspect. I would also be interested in best practice with DevOps and Re-architecting for the cloud. Maybe best as Jesse Carter suggests, ask MS sales rep?

Comment: Aside from not being a programming question, it's *very* broad and opinion-soliciting. There's simply no way to answer this objectively. That's why it's off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I went through this recently and I can share a few tips here since I'm also not aware of a DevOps specific platform to share this on StackExhange.

As far as organizing your subscriptions go look at Azure Pay-As-You-Go Dev/Test Subscriptions [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0023p/)
or Enterprise Dev/Test [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0148p/) if you are an Enterprise Agreement customer. These are aimed at development teams, you get discounted rates since you don't pay for software licenses that are already included in your MSDN subscription.

It is best to use individual developer subscriptions for exploration, POC etc while running your main dev workload in the Dev-Test subscription. It looks tempting to try and save a buck by spreading the work across multiple MSDN subscriptions to use the credits but I wouldn't recommend it. It becomes a pain to manage 20~30 subscriptions and they can run out of credits and things stop working. If you remove the spending limit on all the subscriptions you run the risk of racking up a huge bill accidently if multiple devs leave VMs on or add premium storage to VMs etc.

As far as DevOps go, use [RBAC](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/) and [Azure Active Directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-whatis/) to manage access and certificates for your DevOps tooling, build servers, release management etc don't use individual developer credentials for this.

And I agree with the other comments, get in touch with MS as well, this is just the tip of the iceberg but it will get you started.